# What does initial level of GDP mean?

Tags: modeling, econometrics, growth-model

This might come as a very trivial thing and way below standards of this group but I am struggling to figure out what do the authors mean when they say that they have used initial level of income in growth regressions? assuming that the first obervation in the sample is 120, is it something like this:

Year GDP
1991 120
1992 120
1993 120

or something like this:

Year GDP
1991 120
1992 .
1993 .

or is it just the lagged value of levels?

an example of this type of models is the following:

Benhabib, J., & Spiegel,M.M. (1994). The role of human capital in economic development: Evidence from aggregate cross-country data. Journal of Monetary Economics, 34(2), 143–173.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think the authors meant something like this:

$gdp.growth_{i,t} = \beta_0 + \beta_1 gdp_{i,0} + \beta_2 pop.growth_{i,t} + \beta_3 investment_{i,t} +...$

where $i$ is the index of the country, and $t$ the index of the time period. In this regression you want to assess the effect on $gdp.growth$  of eg. population growth, level of investment, etc. and of the initial gdp level (of country $i$ at time $0$, notated $gdp_{i,0}$).

So for instance if you want to estimate this model on data from Brazil (GDP 50 in 1950) and Holland (GDP 100 in 1950) from 1950 to 2000, you would create an extra variable $gdp0$, equal to 50 for all observations from Brazil, and 100 for all observations from Holland. This allows you to take into account the fact that Brazil was intitially relatively poor compared to Holland, which probably had an effect on the compared subsequent GDP growth  of both countries.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example sounds right. In the second case all observations after 1991 would typically be dropped from the analysis, so that is not what you want. Your third option would be called lagged GDP and not initial GDP.